# Unable to assign values to stack

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

Here is the code for my Stack Implementation

```
class stack
{
    private:
        int top;
        int arr[10];

    public:
        Stack()
        {
            top = -1;
            for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        //further code below
```

And this is the method to display the Stack

```
void disp()
    {
        for (int i=9; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
```

When I am calling the disp() method using class stack object it is printing these values :

```
16, 0, 14882528, 0, 34, 0, 8, 0, 4199705, 0
```

But I have assigned 0 to all the values of arr[10] in Stack() constructor.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Code is not compilable as it is. Class name and constructor name does not match, also constructor is returning a value?

Comment: `Stack() : top(-1), arr({0})` seems like a lot less mess than this.

Comment: Tip: `return` with a value inside a constructor is not a thing.

Comment: `Stack()` is not a constructor for `class stack`. Capitalization matters in C++.

Comment: this code should not compile without errors or at least warnings

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen the error really was because of Capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the typing errors and removing the return "solves" the problem. But your output is not reproducible at all:

```
#include <iostream>

class Stack
{
    private:
        int top;
        int arr[10];

    public:
        Stack()
        {
            top = -1;
            for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        //further code below

        void disp()
    {
        for (int i=9; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i] <<  std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack s;
    s.disp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code as below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Stack
{
private:
    int top;
    int arr[10];

public:
    Stack()
    {
        top = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
        // return 0; NOTE: constructor could not return a value
    }
    
    void disp()
    {
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack s1;
    s1.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

And it gave me these:

```
$ ./a.exe
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I really do not know what you are asking.